# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i'm new to laravel, and i found few decent tutorials to help me understand and get started with it.
the problem is-> whenever i want to use the post method this exception raises `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`
but  unlike, maybe 99% of who asked similar questions, in my case it says the exception is `in RouteCollection.php line 218`, which is unusual but not to `laravel 5.2.x`

the following is the methode post in routes.php:

```
Route::post('/ajouter_produit', 
[
    'uses'=>'ProductController@addProduct',
    'as'=>'ajouter_produit',
]);
```

i even tried adding this method to a middleware route group but the problem remained.

this is my controller:

```
public function addProduct (Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'label'=>'required|alpha',
        'prix'=>'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $prod = new Product();
    $prod->label=$request['label'];
    $prod->type=$request['type'];
    $prod->prix=$request['prix'];

    $prod->save();

    return view('welcome');

}
```

and this is my form:

```
<form action="{{ route('ajouter_produit') }}" method="post" >

    <input type="text" name="label" id="label"/>

    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="1">Par unité</option>
        <option value="2" selected>Par kilo</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="prix" id="prix"/>

    <button type="submit">Ajouter</button>

    <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token"/>
```

i also tried this but it raised the same problem:

```
Route::post('/trypost', function () {
    return 'hello post';
});
```

can you please help me !!

if you need any other source just ask for it. 
Every effort will be much appreciated. ***thank you***

Comment: Missing method get. First you should create route with method get return view. Next, in view page you call method post validate and save to your model.

Comment: You can verify your route using command `php artisan route:list`

Comment: already tried that.. didn't work

Comment: Check page view blade. Error endif

Comment: OMG thank youuu @mydo47 it worked!! i can't believe i didn't think of that!! thank youuu

Comment: @mydo47why don't you write your suggestion in the answer section so that i can mark it as solved ??

Comment: Pleased to help. No problem, keep working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"@mydo47: Missing method get. First you should create route with method get return view. Next, in view page you call method post validate and save to your model." this solved it

Answer (score 1):

take note that if you are using `route()`, it is expecting route name, such as `user.store` or `user.update`.

so my suggestion is, try use `url()` for your open form

```
<form action="{{ url('ajouter_produit') }}" method="post" >
```

more details on laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#urls)

Comment: got no problem with that, because it works with other get methods.it worked thanks to @mydo47's suggestion :D